# Standing Orders with SQL / HQL

Tags: sql, hql, repeat

I implemented an own program to manage my incomes and expenses some years ago. However, I realized that I need some kind of "standing orders" - incomes or expenses which repeat monthly, quarterly or yearly. I would add them in an own table (with the value, description, start and end date, repetition rate, ...). But how do I query them with SQL/HQL in a smart way? For example: I want all incomes for a given month. Now I have to run through all entries and check somehow whether the start date plus a multiple of the repetition rate "hits" the current month. Seems to me very cumbersome. Is there an easy way to implement such operations?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering my own question, but in the meantime I think that it is not that difficult. Even when using HQL it is possible to calculate the number of months between two dates (if not with an existing function, it can still be done in the HQL expression using an obvious formula). Of course one has to handle the case correctly with days which exist in one month but not in the other (e.g., february), but this is a detail which can likely be ignored in my case.

Knowing the number of months between the current month, a simple modulo expression can check whether the current month is "hit" by the standing order. The rest is simple.